# How to use a QVector inside a QScriptEngine

Tags: qt, qscript

First: **Qt 4.7**

I would like to access a `QVector<double>` inside a script, which is the return value of an object member function. I.e. I've passed the object to the script, and it has property set and get functions which have `QVector<double>` as arguments/return values respectively. 
I have done the following:

in its own header:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector<double>)
```

when I set the engine up:

```
_engine = new QScriptEngine()
qScriptRegisterSequenceMetaType< QVector<double> >(_engine);
```

My object (`CalcDataVector`) has the following public slots (`_value` is a protected member):

```
QVector<double> value() { return _value; }
void value(QVector<double> data) { _value = data; }
```

And I send the object to the script engine like this:

```
CalcDataVector *v = new CalcDataVector(); // paraphrasing.. 
QObject *object = v;
QScriptValue value = engine()->newQObject(object);
engine()->globalObject().setProperty("in", value);
```

I want to access the vector in v inside the script :

```
var test  = in.value()
```

Which, as I am new to qscript, may have a blindingly obvious syntax error. Please enlighten me!

I get the syntax error:

> Syntax Error: Parse Error.

I can manipulate the object I'm sending in other ways, so I know it's there.

edit: I also send an output variable of the same type as the input. I can do the following:

```
var test = [ 100, 200, 300 ]
out.value(test)
```

but not

```
var test = [ 100, 200, 300 ]
in.value(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

So...it turns out that "in" is a reserved word in javascript/ECMA!